# Gravityform registration add-on update user feed

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, user-registration

I'm using gravity form registration add-on to create users with a specific role X, I used a (create user) feed for this and assigned it to this role. Now I need the current user with role X to Update his role to Z, I going to create a form with (update user feed). The issue I face is, I don't want the user to be updated automatically, I need the same manual activation function exist in (create user feed)
so the sequence going to be after the user X submit the form I going to show him a confirmation message telling him to wait until we validate his request